# How can Perl remove tags from an XML file?

Tags: xml, perl

I have a sample XML file as below, and I want to remove hashref, Perldata, and also item key value from my output.
My main concern is this:

I have lots of XML file as below with different variables, I want to use a code to remove unnecessary tags automatically without introducing each tag in my Perl code?

Input

```xml
<perldata>
 <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab680">
  <item key="employee">
   <arrayref memory_address="0xa7dc1a8">
    <item key="0">
     <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab584">
      <item key="age">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab338">
        <item key="dob">10-02-2000</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="department">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab1d0">
        <item key="departmentname">Operations</item>
        <item key="title">Manager</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="location">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab068">
        <item key="town">
         <hashref memory_address="0xa7aaffc">
          <item key="county">East</item>
          <item key="name">Auchinleck</item>
         </hashref>
        </item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="name">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab518">
        <item key="forename">John</item>
        <item key="surname">Down</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="************">M</item>
     </hashref>
    </item>
    <item key="1">
     <hashref memory_address="0xa7aae64">
      <item key="age">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7aac90">
        <item key="dob">05-03-2000</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="department">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa78c490">
        <item key="departmentname">Internet</item>
        <item key="title">Watcher</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="location">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa798da4">
        <item key="town">
         <hashref memory_address="0xa798d38">
          <item key="county">South</item>
          <item key="name">BB</item>
         </hashref>
        </item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="name">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7aadf8">
        <item key="forename">Cr</item>
        <item key="surname">Moral</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="************">M</item>
     </hashref>
    </item>
   </arrayref>
  </item>
 </hashref>
</perldata>
```

my preferred output is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <employee>
    <value name="************">M</value>
    <age>
      <dob>01-04-2000</dob>
    </age>
    <department>
      <departmentname>Operations</departmentname>
      <title>Manager</title>
    </department>
    <location>
      <town>
        <county>Somewhere</county>
        <name>Someplace</name>
      </town>
    </location>
    <name>
      <forename>John</forename>
      <surname>Down</surname>
    </name>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <value name="************">M</value>
    <age>
      <dob>12-12-2000</dob>
    </age>
    <department>
      <departmentname>Internet</departmentname>
      <title>Researcher</title>
    </department>
    <location>
      <town>
        <county>Somewhere</county>
        <name>Othertown</name>
      </town>
    </location>
    <name>
      <forename>Jane</forename>
      <surname>Doe</surname>
    </name>
  </employee>
</data>
```

**Update:** The OP added this code in an answer to the question (which has been deleted because it wasn't an answer). I've reformatted it slightly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Dumper;
use TAP3::Tap3edit;
$Data::Dumper::Indent=1;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;

my $dump = new XML::Dumper;
use File::Basename;

my $perl = '';
my $xml = '';
my $tap3 = TAP3::Tap3edit->new();

foreach my $file(glob 'LB*')
{
  my $files= basename($file);
  my $filename=$files.".xml\n";
  print $filename;
  $tap3->decode($files) || die $tap3->error;
  $perl = $tap3->structure;
  $dump->pl2xml($perl, $filename);
}
```

Comment: What module are you using? Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: It's Perl. I am updating . Thanks for mention it.

Comment: Three hours later and the question is still tagged with both Perl and Java. I'll remove the Java tag for you, but please do it yourself in future.

Comment: [Crossposted from PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116740), where I [provided](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116742) a potential solution. In fact, that's where you copied your "preferred output" from...

Comment: Dear Haukex, I tried your code and yes it works for above sample but i want to find another way for this. I want to give my input files which are more than 10,000 files and get the XML format without any hashref and perldata and... I have said that i am so new with Perl i need help.

Comment: @CodeGirl: A complete question includes: code, short example input, expected output for that input, actual current output including any error messages, and a description of the desired vs. actual behavior. Some examples if what you haven't told us: What do the input files look like (names, contents, etc.), what the return value of `$tap3->structure` looks like (`print Dumper($perl);`), and what you want the output of merging these 10k files to look like. If you're completely new to Perl, I can recommend [perlintro](https://perldoc.pl/perlintro) and https://learn.perl.org/ .

Comment: I completely understand what you mean and I will consider your advice for any other questions which I will post. I want 10k files to look like XML tags, I mean not in the above format (Input). I don't want to see memory_address and also I don't want to see <item key="Value">1000</item> I want to see it like <Value>1000</Value>.just a simple and handy XML file. I read a lot yesterday and it seems XML:: Dumper change the structure of XML file as Input I shared above. but this format doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer is "Don't use XML::Dumper", and that your real question is "How can I dump Perl to XML?".

There's a bit of a common problem here. In your Perlmonks post [removing perldata , hashref from XML file](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116740) (um, always note that there are existing discussions no matter where they are), you start with the wonky data structure. But, that's not actually your problem, which is to output a Perl structure as XML. You've posed a different problem than the one you already have, which is sometimes called the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). That's why the good questioners around here tend to always ask clarifying questions.

---

My first thought was that you have a Perl data structure, which I'm guessing is a hash ref:

```
$perl = $tap3->structure;
```

You can walk through that and delete or modify anything that you don't want. That would be my first approach because I could just use basic Perl features to do that. If you can show us that data structure, we might be able to come up with something easy:

```
say Dumper( $perl );
```

It seems that the artifacts that you see may come from [XML::Dumper](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=103145), so you are introducing that by using a poor tool. I realized this after I'd already written the program, so you get that for free, I guess.

Also, if you have posted a problem somewhere else, most people expect you to note that in your question. I was a bit let down that I'd put some of work into this but there'd already been a lot of discussion in [removing perldata , hashref from XML file](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11116740) on Perlmonks.

---

But, since I've done this sort of XML processing before with Apple property lists (that stupidly do the say sort of generic structure with dictionaries and arrays), here's a small [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) program. I think this gets you most of the way there, but I didn't check the output closely. You can play with Twig to adjust this to your taste.

[XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) descends into your XML structure. You can define "handlers" for each sort of node. This handler is a subroutine reference that gets the current node in `$_`, Perl's topic variable. The `perldata` handler is simple because it merely changes the name to `data` by using `set_tag`:

```
        perldata  => sub { $_->set_tag( 'data' )  },
```

The module is a bit intimidating at first because there's so much that you can do, but once you get used to it you have a very powerful tool.

The next part is a bit more complex. You want to take all the children of `hashref` and `arrayref`tags and move them up one level.

```
    arrayref  => \&move_up_children,
    hashref   => \&move_up_children,
```

These take a reference to a named subroutine `move_up_children` so I don't repeat a bunch of code. Part of Twig allows you to "cut" child nodes and "paste" them into other nodes. In this case, cut the children under `hashref` or `arrayref` and paste them into whatever contains `hashref` or `arrayref`. After that, delete the now empty `hashref` or `arrayref`:

```
sub move_up_children {
    my $parent = $_->parent;
    for my $child ( $_->cut_children ) {
        $child->paste( $parent );
        }
    $_->delete;
    }
```

I'm not going to go through the `item` handling. Since that tag has a generic use, I need to test which use I've encountered. There's four cases:

- That `********` value
- a key that is not a number (so not a child of the now gone `arrayref`) but not `employee` (a child of the now gone `hashref`)
- a key that is `employee` (a child of the now gone `hashref`)
- everything else, which are numeric keys (a child of the now gone `arrayref`)

---

```
#!perl
use v5.30;

use XML::Twig;

# just a way to get everything into one string
my $xml = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $twig=XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers =>
    {
    perldata  => sub { $_->set_tag( 'data' )  },
    arrayref  => \&move_up_children,
    hashref   => \&move_up_children,
    item      => sub {
        my $parent = $_->parent;
        my $key = $_->{'att'}{'key'};
        if( $key =~ m/\A \*+ \z/x ) {
            $_->set_tag( 'value' );
            $_->del_att( 'key' );
            $_->set_att( name => $key );
            }
        elsif( $key =~ /\D/ and $key ne 'employee' ) {
            $_->set_tag( $key );
            $_->del_att( 'key' );
            }
        elsif( $key eq 'employee' ) {
            local $_ = $_;
            move_up_children();
            }
        else {
            $_->set_tag( 'employee' );
            $_->del_att( 'key' );
            }
        },
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',  # output will be nicely formatted
    );
$twig->parse( $xml );
my $new_xml = $twig->toString;
say $new_xml;

sub move_up_children {
    my $parent = $_->parent;
    for my $child ( $_->cut_children ) {
        $child->paste( $parent );
        }
    $_->delete;
    }

__DATA__
<perldata>
 <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab680">
  <item key="employee">
   <arrayref memory_address="0xa7dc1a8">
    <item key="0">
     <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab584">
      <item key="age">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab338">
        <item key="dob">10-02-2000</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="department">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab1d0">
        <item key="departmentname">Operations</item>
        <item key="title">Manager</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="location">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab068">
        <item key="town">
         <hashref memory_address="0xa7aaffc">
          <item key="county">East</item>
          <item key="name">Auchinleck</item>
         </hashref>
        </item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="name">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7ab518">
        <item key="forename">John</item>
        <item key="surname">Down</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="************">M</item>
     </hashref>
    </item>
    <item key="1">
     <hashref memory_address="0xa7aae64">
      <item key="age">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7aac90">
        <item key="dob">05-03-2000</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="department">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa78c490">
        <item key="departmentname">Internet</item>
        <item key="title">Watcher</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="location">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa798da4">
        <item key="town">
         <hashref memory_address="0xa798d38">
          <item key="county">South</item>
          <item key="name">BB</item>
         </hashref>
        </item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="name">
       <hashref memory_address="0xa7aadf8">
        <item key="forename">Cr</item>
        <item key="surname">Moral</item>
       </hashref>
      </item>
      <item key="************">M</item>
     </hashref>
    </item>
   </arrayref>
  </item>
 </hashref>
</perldata>
```

The output gets pretty close to what you want, perhaps with some ordering issues:

```
<data>
  <employee>
    <value name="************">M</value>
    <name>
      <surname>Moral</surname>
      <forename>Cr</forename>
    </name>
    <location>
      <town>
        <name>BB</name>
        <county>South</county>
      </town>
    </location>
    <department>
      <title>Watcher</title>
      <departmentname>Internet</departmentname>
    </department>
    <age>
      <dob>05-03-2000</dob>
    </age>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <value name="************">M</value>
    <name>
      <surname>Down</surname>
      <forename>John</forename>
    </name>
    <location>
      <town>
        <name>Auchinleck</name>
        <county>East</county>
      </town>
    </location>
    <department>
      <title>Manager</title>
      <departmentname>Operations</departmentname>
    </department>
    <age>
      <dob>10-02-2000</dob>
    </age>
  </employee>
</data>
```

Comment: I am so thankful for this useful and perfect explanation. everything is so clear for me,I also read [link]https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/03/process-xml-data-with-xmltwig/ which you shared before, now i faced with 2 errors: 1) you seem to have used the parse method on a filename (LC.xml), you probably want parsefile instead at twig.pl line 70. and also after commenting this part 2) Can't call method "say" without a package or object reference at twig.pl line 74.for this issue I tried - cpan use feature 'say';  and - cpan use feature ':5.12'; but they didn't work.

Comment: It sounds like you have a new question, so you can post a new question here. For the first one, the error message tells you what to do. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a [known problem](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=103145) with the module. And given that this bug was raised in 2015 and there hasn't been a new release of the module since 2006, I'd guess that this module has been abandoned and the bug (along with [many others](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=XML-Dumper)) isn't going to be fixed.

I'd recommend looking for a different XML processing module. I like [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Dumper) (but I also hear good things about [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig)).

Comment: I have been searched for this issue more than weeks and so tired of not finding an easy solution, Thanks for your guidance i will have look at them and try to use them.

Comment: Re "*It looks like this is a known problem with the module.*", No. 1) The module works as intended, which is to serialize a data structure in a way that it can be deserialized (like Data::Dumper attempts to do). Note that the OP's format can't be deserialized back into the original structure without additional info. 2) The linked issue is merely a complaint about the undocumented `memory_address` attributes (which are probably used to handle multiple references to the same var). Getting rid of these attributes would not be enough for the OP.

Comment: so what should i do? doesnt this format relates to version of my perl which has been installed? I am downgrading my perl and hope to nit face with this format. Hope it works fine.

Comment: Downgrading Perl will not help. You need to find a different way to turn your Perl data structure into XML.